# CPU Running 50% or higher on HP Pavilion dv6

Tags: cpu

I have been running Ubuntu 14.04 on my HP Pavilion dv6 for 2 and half years now. For the most part, it runs perfect, however recently I have discovered CPU monitors and have realized that my CPU is idling at around 27%-40% and if I am using Firefox, downloading/uploading, or using multiple applications at once it skyrockets to 50%-99% (and this is no joke).

I know that this particular model is famous for overheating. I have had this thing since 2011, and ran windows 7 on it before switching over to Ubuntu. But I have never considered my CPU being the deal.

It has discrete dual graphics cards, as well as two processors.

I will give my specs below

What I am really curious about is whether I should be running the current proprietary drivers and what I should do to cool down my CPU for my particular model? Or, if it is a lost cause.

Computer
Processor   2x AMD Turion(tm) II P540 Dual-Core Processor
Memory  5849MB (2674MB used)
Operating System    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS
User Name   rin (Rin)
Date/Time   Mon 07 Mar 2016 12:23:42 PM MST
Display
Resolution  1366x768 pixels
OpenGL Renderer Gallium 0.4 on AMD RS880
X11 Vendor  The X.Org Foundation
Multimedia
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
Audio Adapter   HDA-Intel - HDA ATI HDMI
Input Devices
Power Button
Lid Switch
Power Button
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad
Video Bus
Video Bus
ST LIS3LV02DL Accelerometer 
HDA ATI SB Front Headphone
HDA ATI SB Mic
HDA ATI HDMI HDMI/DP,pcm    3=
HP WMI hotkeys
HP Webcam
Printers
No printers found
SCSI Disks
ATA SAMSUNG HM500JJ 
hp CDDVDW TS-L633R
Operating System
Version
Kernel  Linux 3.13.0-79-generic (x86_64)
Compiled    #123-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 19 14:27:58 UTC 2016
C Library   Unknown
Default C Compiler  GNU C Compiler version 4.8.4 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1)
Distribution    Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS

Comment: Also, the fan is always running.

Comment: Alright, so I ran the top command in terminal and I can see java taking up most of my CPU. I watched it jump from around 30%, up to around 50%, and shot up 103% before it dropped back down to around 48-50%. That is java specifically. I am super curious as to why it would run like it is.

Comment: Does it the CPU usage go down when you kill the Java process ? What do you see when you run `ps -ww -fp <processid>` in a terminal ? (You can see the process id in `top` or in the system monitor, and you can kill java from the system monitor too.)

Comment: Yes my CPU usage almost hits 8% when I kill the process.

Comment: I was not able to run that command in terminal. I recieved the message:

Comment: bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'newline'

Comment: Welp, I ended up solving it by finding a forum post on ubuntuforums.org. Freenet ended up being the culprit that was eating up my CPU. I noticed that at startup, my systems CPU was maxed out. I hadn't thought about Freenet in a while, downloaded it, used it once or twice, spaced it. But the forum post mentions that Freenet starts up with the system boot, so it would make since.

Comment: I uninstalled it and walla! My CPU is running just fine.  Here is the forum post for anyone who is having the same relative issue: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=792676

Answer (score 0):

I ended up solving my CPU issue by removing Freenet from my system. Here is the forum I used to help me. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=792676